# Bluetooth LE on Debian Raspberry Pi in Java

Tags: java, maven, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, java-native-library

When i pair and connect with a BLE Device with linux commands everything works.
Now i want my java program to read the same values.
I looked up a lot of stuff and all libraries are based on tinyB https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb
Im using the bluetooth manager lib https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sputnikdev/bluetooth-manager where tinyB is integrated.
Now the problem: When i start the jar on my raspberry it says: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no javatinyb in java.library.path
The solution should be here: https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb/issues/75
But because i use maven i cannot find where the native libraries are located and how i should modify the library path.
So my real question is: How can i use native libraries on a Raspberry with Debian?
Thank you in advance